# polymorphic struct declaration

Tags: c++, struct, polymorphism

I am sure that this question has been asked and answered before, but I am having trouble searching without the proper terminology.

I have two unique structs A & B (not classes).  My code uses functional overloading to treat the structs differently.  I don't understand how to handle the declaration polymorphism.  I apologize for a pseudocode example.

```
if( flag ==1 ){
   declare stuct A scoped to main
}
else{
   declare stuct B scoped to main
}
```

The pseudo code above will not work since the declarations are scoped within the if statements.  My "real" code doesn't compile because of the scoping issues I am trying to describe.

**EDIT**

Clarification:

Depending on a specified flag (arg) I want to declare one of two different structs.  Once the proper struct is declared all polymorphism is already handled by operation overloading.

Thanks

Comment: Try to create dynamic instances using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: You might be able to use pre-processor macros to define the one you want if the `flag` is known at compile time. But I think you need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: See [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: `(not classes)` There is no distinction in C++. Both keywords `struct` and `class` are _user-defined types_ and behave in precisely the same way. The only difference between using the two keywords is some access level defaults in the definition syntax, but the resulting kinds of types are still indistinct. That is, in `struct A { int x; }; class B { public: int x; };`, the types `A` and `B` are entirely identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question fundamentally has nothing to do with structs, or classes, or polymorphism, (though the solution does require the latter).

It's about trying to declare objects of different types, conditionally, without running afoul of block scoping. The simple answer is that you can't.

The usual approach is to use a late-initialised smart pointer instead:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>

struct A { virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

void f(A&);

int main()
{
   srand(time(0));
   const int x = rand();

#if 0
   /** Can't do this: **/
   if (x > 500)
      B obj;
   else
      C obj;

   f(obj);
#endif

   /** Can do this: **/
   std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
   if (x > 500)
      ptr.reset(new B);
   else
      ptr.reset(new C);

   f(*ptr);

#if 0
   /** Some older examples may propose this: **/
   A* ptr = NULL;
   if (x > 500)
      ptr = new B;
   else
      ptr = new C;

   f(*ptr);

   delete ptr;
   ptr = NULL;
#endif
}
```

Since `f` accepts a reference, polymorphic is maintained even though you're feeding it a `A`.

Typically you'd actually invoke a member function through `ptr`, using virtual dispatch to ensure that the correct code is executed:

```
   std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
   if (x > 500)
      ptr.reset(new B);
   else
      ptr.reset(new C);

   ptr->someFunction();
```

No function overloads required.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know where I could find an example?

Comment: @zev.kronenberg: Scroll up slightly :)