# Expand scope of a variable initialized in a if/else sequence

Tags: c++, scope

I'm writing a piece of code in which I'd like to use a different constructor of a class depending on a condition. So far I've used `if` and `else` statements to construct the object, but the instance is then 'trapped' in the brackets and can't be used further in the code.

Here is what it looks like in code:

```
if (my_boolean){
    MyClass my_object(arg1); //calling a first constructor
}
else {
    MyClass my_object(arg1,arg2); //calling another constructor
}
//more code using my_object
```

I tried using the `static` keyword without success so far. Is there a common way of conditionally using different constructors without having to redefine the constructors?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23138929/560648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the following :)

```
MyClass my_object = my_boolean ? MyClass(arg1) : MyClass(arg1,arg2);
```

Take into account that this code will work even if the class has no default constructor.

Here is a demonstrative example

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main () 
{
    struct Point
    {
        Point( int x ) : x( x ) {}
        Point( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
    };

    std::srand( ( unsigned )std::time( 0 ) );

    Point p = std::rand() % 2 ? Point( 1 ) : Point( 1, 2 );

    std::cout << "p.x = " << p.x << ", p.y = " << p.y << std::endl;  

    return 0; 
}
```

I have gotten the following output

```
p.x = 1, p.y = 2
```

What output have you gotten? :)

Comment: Thank you for the input, of all the offered solutions this was definitely the quicker to implement, and so I opted for it ;)

Comment: @Learningisamess Note this works only for simple yes/no decisions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes indeed, I'll remember to use a (smart) pointer in a more sophisticated case.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I showed a general approach for any compound condition. The idea is that you can define a local object is some function and then copy this object in the target object using either copy constructor or move constructor. Simply substitute the ternary operator with some function call.

Comment: Note that this requires an accessible copy or move constructor.

Comment: _@Vlad_ I'm with @MikeSeymour, I believe the smart pointer is the least intrusive solution for a bit more complicated cases than a simple struct like this.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a variable outside of a given scope, it must be declared outside that scope.

```
void foo()
{
    MyClass my_object;
    if (my_boolean){
        my_object = MyClass(arg1); //calling a first constructor,
                                   //then copy or move assignment
    }
    else {
        my_object = MyClass(arg1,arg2); //calling another constructor,
                                   //then copy or move assignment
    }
    //more code using my_object
}
//Can no longer access my_object
```

If you want to do it this way, I suggest defining a [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_operator) if the default will not work for your purposes (or there isn't a default move assignment operator).

Also, the code where you are using `my_object` may be cleaner if you move the `if`/`else` blocks and object construction to a separate function, then do something like:

```
MyClass my_object = make_object(my_boolean);
```

Or, if `arg1` and `arg2` aren't global,

```
MyClass my_object = make_object(my_boolean, arg1, arg2);
```

If creating an object gets more complicated than what you've asked about here, you may wish to look into the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: It also may or may not be useful to move it into a function so it becomes `MyClass my_object = obj_init(my_boolean);`

Comment: @MooingDuck I was thinking of adding that, but I realized that the contents of the function would be identical to the code I posted, except the return type of the function would be `MyClass` and there would be a `return my_object;` at the end; not enough of a difference to justify doubling the code in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't bother writing code for it, just a sentence.  I'm not saying a function is better than your answer, merely that _sometimes_ (definitely not always) a function may be good for code similar to this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a smart pointer instead of a direct instance:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_object;

if (my_boolean) {
     //calling a first constructor
    my_object.reset(new MyClass(arg1));
}
else {
    //calling another constructor
    my_object.reset(new MyClass(arg1,arg2));
}
//more code using my_object
```

In contrast to some other solutions proposed here, this will also work for bigger `if() {} else if() {}` sequences, or `switch` blocks.

---

In case you can't use a compiler capable of the latest standard, you can use the good old [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) in the exactly same manner.

> *"I tried using the `static` keyword without success so far."*

Good so! A `static` variable is certainly not what you want here.

Comment: Why not just copy-assignment?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Also a good alternative, but I wanted to deal with what the OP actually shows.

Comment: I'd just use `my_object.reset(new MyClass(...));`. But there's no need for dynamic allocation, as Vlad's answer shows.

Comment: Just a note: This kind of smart pointer is C++11 only. If you want a smart pointer in earlier standards of C++ I'd recommend the boost library.

Comment: @Praetorian I have to admit, I'm not that well versed with `std::unique_ptr`, mostly used `std::auto_ptr` until now. But I didn't want to give it as a reference (since it's deprecated). But you're right, for either case the `reset()` function would be more efficient.

Comment: @stix No, no boost necessary. In that case I'd simply use a `std::auto_ptr`.