# initialize object depending on if statement

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to work with `ifstream` and `istringstream` using only on variable. I know that both of them are children of `istream`. So, I am trying to make only one variable of type `istream` and the intialize depending on some input.

The real problem is that I asked the user to input file path or content of file. Then, I will read it line by line. I tried to do like this.

```
istream * stream;
if(isFile){
   ifstream a("fileOrContent");
   stream = &a;
} else {
   istringstream a("fileOrContent");
   stream = &a;
}
getline(stream,line)
// do something with line
```

I also tried this

```
ifstream stream;
if(isFile){
   ifstream stream("fileOrContent");
} else {
   istringstream stream("fileOrContent");
}
getline(stream,line)
// do something with line
```

Currently, I using two full copies of my code for each one. Any suggestions of how I might do it?

Thank you

Comment: Non-pointer variables go out of scope with the closing brace of the level they are on. In this case, both of the `a` variables will be out of scope after the `if`, and will not be valid to use a point to them.

Comment: You haven't told us the problem you're experiencing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand scope of a variable initialized in a if/else sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638158/expand-scope-of-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is something like this:

```
istream * stream;
if(isFile){
   stream = new ifstream("fileOrContent");
} else {
   stream = new istringstream("fileOrContent");
}
getline(*stream,line)
```

That said you should use a smart pointer to hold the istream pointer to avoid memory leaks, as pointed out by @πάντα ῥεῖ.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using something like `std::unique_ptr<std::istream>` instead of advising a raw pointer.

Answer (score 5):

How about refactoring your code like this:

```
void process(std::istream & is)
{
    // ....
}

int main()
{
    if (isFile)
    {
        std::ifstream is("foo.txt");
        process(is);
    }
    else
    {
        std::istringstream is(str);
        process(is);
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) I wonder why one should use smart pointers when the solution is actually so simple.

Comment: @ChristianHackl _'when the solution is actually so simple'_ Well, it requires refactoring, which might come up a _not so simple_ task for existing code bases. The OP didn't really clarify the situation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: because l33t C++ hax0r must use `new` to show skillz?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: In this case, the refactoring would be completely local, and I can hardly imagine a scenario in which it would require significantly more coding work than the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The actual point is _intrusiveness_ IMHO, as I mentioned in the Q&A, I have marked as possible dupe.

Comment: This *may* be troublesome because the `is` variable is not available after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

i just did something similar to this. you are almost there

```
if(isFile) {
    stream = new ifstream("whatever");
} else {
    stream = new istringstream("whatever");
}

getline(*stream, line);
```

make sure to delete it though

Comment: At least this answer mentions deletion is necessary for dealing with raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manage the memory yourself, you can use an `unique_ptr` which will automatically free the memory when it goes out of scope:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<std::istream> stream;
if(isFile){
   stream = std::unique_ptr<std::istream>(new ifstream("fileOrContent"));
} else {
   stream = std::unique_ptr<std::istream>(new istringstream("fileOrContent"));
}
getline(*stream,line)
```

Comment: For pre c++11 standard the `std::auto_ptr` will work well, and for both of these solutions, using the `reset()` function is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `getline` and the "do something with line" in a function which takes a `std::istream &` argument.

Then create either an `ifstream` or an `istringstream`, and place the function call into the if/else branches.

```
void DoSomethingWithLine(std::istream &stream)
{
    getline(stream,line);
    // do something with line
}

if (isFile){
   ifstream a("fileOrContent");
   DoSomethingWithLine(a);
} else {
   istringstream a("fileOrContent");
   DoSomethingWithLine(a);
}
```

It won't get much simpler than this.