# constructing class & scope

Tags: c++, class, constructor, scope

So I have a question about creating a class object and scope. My program needs to do 3 different things depending on if its called by ./Bank, ./Bank [number], and ./ Bank [number] [string]. I have a Bank class that has 3 contructors that correspond to how the program is started Bank(), Bank(int num), and Bank(int num, string str). The "Bank" is just an array of Customer objects, the default constructor sets a default length of the array, the second constructor lets the user set the length of the array, and the last lets the user set the length and a text file name to populate the array(it uses the info to create a new Customer, then adds the Customer to the array). Can I do this in the main?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  string progName(argv[0]);
  int numCustomers;
  string fileName;
  if(argc == 1){
      Bank bank;
  }
  //get number of customers argument
  if(argc > 1){
      istringstream buf(argv[1]);
      buf >> numCustomers;
      Bank bank(numCustomers);
  }
  //get file name argument
  if(argc > 2){
      istringstream buf(argv[1]);
      buf >> numCustomers;
      fileName = argv[2];
      Bank bank(numCustomers, fileName);
  } // more stuff below
```

and then later on in main call bank.function()? Or does the bank only exist in the if statement scope? I know with a variable it wouldn't exist outside the if statement, but is it different when you create a class inside an if statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Expand scope of a variable initialized in a if/else sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638158/expand-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-a-if-else-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

Each of your `Bank` is created within the scope of an if bloc.  As soon as you exit the block, the variable gest destroyed.   Also for arrgc >2 you create two times the `Bank`.

**The solutions**

Before anything reorganisze your `if`s using else and the right order.

Then, first alternative, if you insist to have these different constructors, is to declare `bank` in the scope of `main()`, which will use the default constructor.  In your ifs, you would create a temporary `Bank` and do an assignement:

```
bank = Bank (...);   // replaces bank with the newly constructed Bank
```

This works, but it's not elegant, because you first create an unused empty bank that will be overwritten.

Second atlernative, would be to use a pointer in the scope of `main()`:  this allows you to use different constructors, and construct only one Bank:

```
int main(...) {
    ... 
    Bank* bankp = nullptr; 
    ...
    if (argc==1) {
        ... 
        bankp = new Bank;   // create a pointer 
        } 
    ...
```

A further improvement would be to use a [shared pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr):

```
  shared_ptr<Bank> bankp; 
  ...
        bankp = make_shared<Bank> (/* parameters of the Bank construtor */);
```

But honnestly, you should **reconsider your design**, because:

- banks tend to have an increasing number of customer,  so starting with a number or customer and increase it later, should be foreseen in your design.
- populating the bank with a file at the construction raises unecessary issues: what if the file is not found (your constructor fails its construction!) ?  What if there are more customers than foreseen in the bank ?
- code of your constructor with the file will be partly redundant with code of the other constructor.

I'll suggest somethink like:

```
class Bank {
...
bool resize(size_t numCustomers);    // resize bank without loosing data.  Returns tue if ok 
bool read(string filename);  // populates the bank, if necessary resizing it. True if ok   
...
}
```

Comment: In response to the "reconsider your design" section, this is a lab from school. This is only the 3rd lab so things are still fairly basic, which is why we are starting with a set number of customers and we don't need to worry about files not being found. Other than that thank you!