# Defining variable type based on a boolean in c++

Tags: c++, scope

Depending on a boolean variable `myBool` I would like to declare a variable `mVect` as a 1D or a 2D vector, i.e.:

```
  if (myBool){
       vector < vector< float > > myVect;
   }
   else{
       vector <float> myVect;
   }

  ///// later.....//////

 //call many instances of overloaded myFn( vector<float>), 
 //or  myFn ( vector<vector<float>)

   //// more stuff.....//
  // call more instances of myFn
```

I'd like the variables to have scope beyond the if statement.  Using a ternary operator as in ([Expand scope of a variable initialized in a if/else sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638158/expand-scope-of-a-variable-initialized-in-a-if-else-sequence?lq=1)) does not seem applicable since the variable types are different.

My motivation for this is that I have an overloaded function `myFn`, one version inputs a `vector`, another puts in a `vector<vector>`.  I'd prefer to not put an if statement in `myFn` to distinguish the cases for performance reasons -- I'd like to call a single `if` statement when declaring and not call a trillion `if` statements when repeatedly calling `myFn`

**edit**:
This is for a physical simulation. I would like to keep the ability to do a 1D or a 2D calculation and myFn does a 1D or a 2D interpolation respectively. I don't want to modify any of the code-base beyond different initializing of variables and I thus want to keep the variable names the same so I can call the same overloaded interpolator, nor do I want an if statement in the interpolator

Comment: What is the real use case? I mean what do you put inside this vectors? I think you can only do it when the two types share a common base type.

Comment: The code to fill the vectors would need to be different too, so you can't just treat these the same. You could easily name them differently to make clear which one you are working with.

Comment: This is for a physical simulation.  I would like to keep the ability to do a 1D or a 2D calculation and myFn does a 1D or a 2D interpolation respectively.  I don't want to modify any of the code-base beyond different initializing of variables and I thus want to keep the variable names the same so I can call the same overloaded interpolator, nor do I want an `if` statement in the interpolator

Comment: If you can tell what you are trying to do, maybe someone can find you a better solution

Comment: You can't have the static type of a variable worked out at runtime. If you post a bit more code we can probably suggest something suitable.

Comment: Is the issue that you would like to keep the `myFn` name the same but have different types it can be called with? If so you might be able to keep the function name `myFn` but take different types with templates by making a specialization for the 2 different types that can be passed in. This is assuming that you pass data of different types in.

Comment: Could you factor out your calls to `myFn` into a template function, then just call `callMyFun(std::vector<float>{})` and `callMyFun(std::vector<std::vector<float>>{})`?

Comment: What does myFn do with a vector of float or vector of vector of float that is so trivial that a dispatch time test of a bool would have a noticeable impact on performance?

Comment: @JSF Linear interpolation, would be the thing that is called the most in the simulation.  Seems silly to have to call a if statement zillions of times, am OK with doing that, but was hoping to have to not put an if statement in myFn

Comment: @db1234 Then you should place the `if` higher up in the calling hierarchy. Also, does this have to be a runtime thing? If you want to play around with different implementations of the same thing and compare performance, you might as well make it a compile-time decision.

Comment: I have thought about making it a compile time decision as well.  I wanted to get community feedback first.  Putting an `if` higher up, if I understand, could mean having to debug in two spots, the code-base is quite large

Comment: @db1234 In professional quality projects of that type, one has anticipated this issue from the start of design.  The most effective solution is to have templated large amounts of code on something representing the number of dimensions being handled.  So all the code that is in common appears in source form once, but in compiled form two (or more) times.  Then all these low level differences can be dealt with as specialization with neither source code distraction nor run time cost.  But if you didn't design that way from the start, retrofitting that may be a large effort.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want a local variable to have different types based on runtime value of a boolean.

This is impossible to acheve in C++. The two options you have are:

1) If the boolean is const (or comes from a constexpr) you can convert you code into a template and use `std::conditional` to pick the right type.

2) Do all the work inside the respective scopes of your `if`, then the variables are different and no problem with them having different types:

```
  if (myBool){
       vector < vector< float > > myVect;
       ...
       myFn(myVect);
   }
   else{
       vector <float> myVect;
       ...
       myFn(myVect);
   }
```

Comment: "This is impossible to acheve in C++." With all this metaprogramming we forget that C++ is object oriented language?

Comment: @Slava: If you meant using polymorphism here than a) OP is clearly interested in built-in `vector` b) would not help with OP's target of making the type of `myVect` to affect `myFn` overload resolution. And finally the type of _variable_ `myVect` would be the same (the interface) which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution - OO. You create a base class with interface that used in your code and interpolator and then inherit 1d or 2d from it based on condition:

```
class MyVector {
public:
   virtual ~MyVector();
...
};

class MyVector1D : public MyVector {
};

class MyVector2D : public MyVector {
};

// usage
std::unique_ptr<MyVector> vector = myBool ? std::make_unique<MyVector1D>() 
                                          : std::make_unique<MyVector2D>();

myFn( vector );
```

Or you can use boost::variant with either visitor pattern or conditional code where that vector is used.

Comment: If you are going to use this, you would have to implement virtual functions to do whatever `myFn` does. This would make `MyVector1D` and `MyVector2D` much more than just vector-wrappers, because the algorithm that uses them is bound to the type. This kind of dependency is usually not recommended (and a common pitfall when over-using OO). The alternative is to have `myFn` figure out the dynamic type, downcast, and call an overloaded function, which is simply moving the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @JorenHeit `MyVector1D` and `MyVector2D` could be thin wrappers and `myFn` would dispatch code based on runtime type by `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Yes, this is the alternative I mentioned, which is moving the problem elsewhere imho.